# Check for null via BinaryOperator

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5, devexpress

```
GroupOperator groupApplyOn = new GroupOperator();
         groupApplyOn.OperatorType = GroupOperatorType.And;
        groupApplyOn.Operands.Add(isB);
        groupApplyOn.Operands.Add(isA);
        groupApplyOn.Operands.Add(isC);
```

where isX  are BinaryOperator ..

```
BinaryOperator isB = new BinaryOperator("VALIDITY", null,
            BinaryOperatorType.Equal);
```

this code gives me error - how to check with `public UnaryOperator IsNull()`  if "VALIDITY" is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [NullOperator](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressDataFilteringNullOperatortopic) instead.